# Falta cygwin1.dll al ejecutar *exe generado en NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

Tengo un sencillo código en C++ en el IDE de *NetBeans 8.0.1*. Ya configuré toda la suite de *Cygwin*.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "iostream"
int main(){
    printf("hola como estas");
    return 0;
}
```

Al compilarlo dentro de *NetBeans*, todo muy bien, pero cuando me dirijo a la carpeta *dist* dentro del proyecto y ejecuto el *.exe*, me lanza este error:

[image: falta cywgin1.dll]

1- ¿Por qué se da dicho problema?

2- ¿Estos *exe* son portables o nativos?

Estoy empezando en C++, necesito generar un *exe* que se pueda ejecutar en diferentes sistemas operativos de *Windows*.

Answer (score 1):

Ya soluciones el error a la pregunta que hice anteriormente
esta es la explicación:
 cygwin necesita un conjunto de `dll` para que funciones los `.exe` generados con él  por lo tanto hay que importar

```
#import <cygwin/cygwin_dll.h>
```

con ello el .exe ya se puede ejecutar directamente  desde la carpeta dist, puesto que se empaqueta dentro del exe las librerías estáticas necesarias.
el codigo quedaria asi:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "iostream"
#import <cygwin/cygwin_dll.h>
int main(){
    printf("hola como estas");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: acabo de intentar la solución pero me sigue apareciendo exactamente el mismo error.